How to formulate L1 norm minimization as a linear programming problem
I want to find the optimal $x$ in this problem:
$$
\min \sum_{i=1}^N |x_i - x^0_i|
$$
s.t.
$$
Ax \leqslant b,
$$
$$
lb \leqslant x \leqslant ub,
$$
where $x$ is a $N\times1$ vector, and $x^0$ is the current observed values (positive or negative).
EDIT: Note the bold part above: the crux of the problem is to find a new vector $x$ whose Manhattan distance to the current observed vector $x^0$ is minimized while satisfying the linear constraints.
I have made it work using scipy.optimize.miminize with the SLSQL algorithm, but performance is not satisfactory. I read that if I formulate this problem as a linear programming problem I can then use scipy.optimize.linprog which should be much faster. But how do I re-write the objective function as a simple linear equation in the form of $C^Tx$?
SOLUTION:
(based on comment below)
Re-write $x_i - x^0_i = y^+_i - y^-_i$, where $y_i$'s are non-negative, and the objective is now to minimize the sum of all $y_i$'s without the absolute-value operation (why?). The trick is to transform the two constraints in terms of a vector $y_i:=[y^+; y^-]$ of dimension $2N \times 1$.
Because $x_i = y^+_i - y^-_i + x_0$, we have:

On first constraint $Ax \leqslant b$:
$\implies A(y^+_i - y^-_i + x_0) \leqslant b$
$\implies A(y^+_i - y^-_i) \leqslant b-Ax_0$
$\implies [A, -A] \cdot y_i \leqslant b-Ax_0$

On second constraint $lb \leqslant x \leqslant ub$:
$\implies lb \leqslant y^+_i - y^-_i + x_0 \leqslant ub$
$\implies lb-x_0 \leqslant y^+_i - y^-_i \leqslant ub-x_0$
$\implies lb-x_0 \leqslant [I, -I] \cdot y_i \leqslant ub-x_0$
where $I$ is the $N \times N$ identity matrix with all ones in the diagonal.


To summarise, the original problem is re-formulated as the following LP problem:
Let $x_i - x^0_i = y^+_i - y^-_i$, and denote $y=[y^+; y^-]$ as the $2N \times 1$ vector that stores all $y_i$'s, then we want to:
$$
\min \sum_{i=1}^{2N} y_i
$$
s.t.
$$
[A, -A] \cdot y_i \leqslant b-Ax_0,
$$
$$
lb-x_0 \leqslant [I, -I] \cdot y_i \leqslant ub-x_0,
$$
$$
y \geqslant 0.
$$
Once $y$ is solved for, we can deduce $x = [I, -I] \cdot y + x_0.$

Try letting $x=x^0+x^+-x^-$ where $x^+,x^-\geq 0$. Then it suffices to minimize $\sum_i(x^+_i+x^-_i)$. Does this help?

@LoganPost No because scipy can only minimize one vector

Apologies I didn't think through the full picture. Now I understand your point.

The comments have the right idea, but let me see if I can fill in some details for you.
In mathematical optimization you do not include an initial guess as part of the objective. We'll therefore rewrite your problem as
\begin{aligned}
\min &\quad \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i \rvert \\
\text{subject to} &\quad \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b} \\
&\quad \mathbf{l} \leq \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{u}
\end{aligned}
We can then write each component as $x_i = y_i^+ - y_i^-$ where $y_i^+$ and $y_i^-$ are non-negative variables. Let us now define $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ by
$$
\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1^+ \\
y_2^+ \\
\vdots \\
y_n^+ \\
y_1^- \\
y_2^- \\
\vdots \\
y_n^-
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and a new optimization problem
\begin{aligned}
\min &\quad \sum_{i=1}^{2n} y_i \\
\text{subject to} &\quad \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & -\mathbf{A} \end{bmatrix} \mathbf{y} \leq \mathbf{b} \\
&\quad \mathbf{l} \leq \begin{bmatrix} 
e_1 & -e_1 \\
e_2 & -e_2 \\
\vdots
\\e_n & -e_n
\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{y} \leq \mathbf{u} \\
&\quad \mathbf{y} \geq 0
\end{aligned}
where $e_k$ is the $k$'th basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. To get a solution to your original problem, you solve this secondary problem and use $\mathbf{y}^*$ to compute $\mathbf{x}^*$.

I don't quite follow this notation. Is your $x_i$ the same as my $x_i$?

Yes, it is. What part is confusing you?

The objective function in my original formulation is to minimise Manhattan distance to $x^0$, which is the current observed values, not "initial guess" (my wording was inaccurate in my original post).  The simple L1 norm is equivalent to minimizing distance to the origin.

Ok, first make a substitution $z_i = x_i - x_i^0$ (and update the constraints accordingly). And then you follow the procedure outlined in my answer.

Do you mind checking my solution above based on your idea? Last time I did anything remotely close to this was 15 years ago

Yes, your edit looks good. As for your question of "why" minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{2N} y_i$, we are forcing both the positive and negative parts of $x_i - x_i^0$ to zero, which is the same as minimizing the absolute value.
